# Latest stable of gcc

Tags: linux, gcc

I need to install the latest stable release of gcc.  I'm looking at all the [gcc releases here](http://gcc.gnu.org/releases.html).  I'm assuming these are all stable releases?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes those are all stable, if you want a development version you would check it out of subversion.

Answer (score 1):

That is a list of the released, stable versions. I think these days there aren't even any development releases, you just grab something from SVN.